# Cordova reloading my files

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, android-emulator, npm

I can't find something about this, I am create a cordova project with NodeJS/npm, see this [link](https://github.com/simnova/webdevdocs/wiki/Installing-PhoneGap-and-Android-Studio-on-Windows), But after create the project I will try to modify him, its like a normal thing to do.

I tryed to edit the file in:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\helloworld\platforms\android\assets\www\index.html
```

and run this code in console:

```
cordova emulate android
```

my files are reloading and my modifications are deleted, the application are deployed into emulator and I can't do nothing. How I can edit my project without this "reloader"? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify here

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\helloworld\www\index.html
```

This modification will be automatically applied to the platform's asset folder after you build the project. And build project first before emulate

```
cordova build android
```